# Drools : how to assign value to variable when using PackageDescr to generate rule?

Tags: java, drools

I'm trying to use PackageDescr to write the following rule :

```
package com.sample 
import com.sample.Data

rule "my rule"
when
   $d: Data( value > 5 || id == 1  )  
then
System.out.println($d);

end
```

This is what I did so far

```
PackageDescr pkg = DescrFactory.newPackage()
            .name("com.sample")
            .newImport().target(Data.class.getName()).end()
            .getDescr();
    RuleDescr testRule = new RuleDescr();

    RelationalExprDescr expr1 = new RelationalExprDescr(">", false, null, new ExprConstraintDescr("value"), new ExprConstraintDescr("5"));
    RelationalExprDescr expr2 = new RelationalExprDescr("==", false, null, new ExprConstraintDescr("id"), new ExprConstraintDescr("1"));
    OrDescr or = new OrDescr();
    PatternDescr patternDescr = new PatternDescr();
    AndDescr and = new AndDescr();

    or.addDescr(expr1);
    or.addDescr(expr2);

    patternDescr.setObjectType(Data.class.getName());
    patternDescr.addConstraint(or);

    and.addDescr(patternDescr);

    testRule.setName("my rule");
    testRule.setLhs(and);
    testRule.setConsequence("System.out.println(\"smthg\");");
    pkg.addRule(testRule);

    String drl = new DrlDumper().dump(pkg);
    System.out.println(drl);
```

and this is the output I got :

```
package com.sample 

import com.sample.Data

rule "my rule"
when
    com.sample.Data( [OR [value > 5, id == 1] ] )  
then
System.out.println("smthg");

end
```

I can't figure out how to assign the result to the variable $d so I can use it in the LHS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `PatternDescr` constructor that takes an identifier:

```
public PatternDescr(String objectType, String identifier)
```

You're currently using the default constructor. By using this constructor you can also omit the call to `setObjectType`.

```
PatternDescr patternDescr = new PatternDescr(Data.class.getName(), "$d");
patternDescr.addConstraint(or);
```

Alternatively if you have your heart set on using the default constructor, there's the `setIdentifier` method that would do the same thing.

(Also this is probably one of the most inefficient ways of writing rules I've possibly ever seen and would strongly suggest you do things the normal way.)

Ref: [Javadoc](https://javadoc.io/static/org.drools/drools-compiler/7.44.0.Final/org/drools/compiler/lang/descr/PatternDescr.html)

Comment: Thank you. but what do you mean by "the normal way"?

Comment: Write your rules as ... well, rules. Or even decision tables. Not programmatically.